# Statistical Aggregate report Intreprtation

Tags: testing, jmeter, stress-testing

It might be a trivial question but please share your experience with me.

I am using Jmeter in GUI mode and added an add on "Statistical Aggregate report" Listener.
But I am unable to interpret the Graph I am getting from this Listener.How could it be useful for the performance testing. What sort of information I am getting ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you've better study [theoretical info](http://www.wilsonmar.com/perfrpt.htm) about performance/load-testing artifacts and metrics first and than decide which listeners/graphs are necessary for your testing.

You could also look onto [jmeter-plugins graphs](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) - they are in many cases more informative/descriptive than jmeter's ones.

**UPDATED:**
Statistical Aggregate Report listener is kind of combination of [Graph Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results) and [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listeners into one chart where you get statistic for 2 important performance characteristics measurements - throughput (hits/sec) + Avg. Response Time (msec) - across the test execution time.

See both listeners descriptions for details about characteristics they are measuring:

> The throughput number represents the actual number of requests/minute
>   the server handled. This calculation includes any delays you added to
>   your test and JMeter's own internal processing time. The advantage of
>   doing the calculation like this is that this number represents
>   something real - your server in fact handled that many requests per
>   minute, and you can increase the number of threads and/or decrease the
>   delays to discover your server's maximum throughput.

Roughly:

```
response time   = "time to last byte"
latency     = "time to first byte"
throughput  = number of requests / time unit
```

For programming realization I'd better look into [source code](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/statsaggvisualizereclipseproject.zip) available.

Comment: Thank you Alies . It is realy helpful to me

Comment: can I have your SkypeId please . My Gmail is chinmay.brahma@gmail.com   I still have few doubts. I can share with you few snapshots over there . I am stuck at some points . Please Help me.

Comment: You can send description of your problems me here to regenmann.at.gmail.com. I'll try to help you if I could.

Comment: Thank you. I have sent you a mail. Awaiting for your response

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue will be occurred with the third party Listener plugin "Statistical Aggregate Report" while we clear the Test Results in JMeter

Stack Trace :

```
ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Clear.doAction(Clear.java:76)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is a new question instead of answer. use [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link to ask new question